# MYSQL select in different table with condition

Tags: mysql, sql, select

**UPDATE**

I know with variable $id the ID of data in table_1. I have two same columns in table_1 and table_2 (with same content). I want to select and show column in table_2 (result).

**TABLE 1**

```
|     ID        |      color      | 
-----------------------------------
       1        |      data1      |     
       2        |      data2      |   
       3        |      data3      |     
       4        |      data4      |   
       5        |      data5      |
```

**TABLE 2**

```
|     ID        |      flower     |      result      | 
------------------------------------------------------
       11       |      data1      |     result1      |    
       12       |      data2      |     result2      |     
       13       |      data3      |     result3      |      
       14       |      data4      |     result4      |       
       15       |      data5      |     result5      |
```

ex
ID = 5
result = result5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Select t2.*, t1.color from t2 inner join t1 on t1.color = t2.data and t1.id = '$id'
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple join will handle this.

```
select t2.result
from table1 t1
join table2 t2
on t1.color = t2.flower
where t1.id = 5
```

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT result FROM t2 JOIN t1 ON (t1.color = t2.data AND t1.id = $id);`

Answer (score 0):

[**<kbd>sqlfiddle</kbd>**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2b8056/3)

```
select t1.id, t2.result
from table1 t1, table2 t2
where
t1.id = <your-id>
and
t1.color = t2.flower;
```

[image]

[**<kbd>sqlfiddle</kbd>**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2b8056/3)

Answer (score 0):

You will need to have something in common with the tabels ... 
Example 
Table 1 : will have ID and color
Table 2 : will have ID, ID_table1, flower, result

and then u can do like this :

```
$select1=mysql_query("select * from table1");
$id_table1=mysql_result($select1,0,'enter the id here');
$select2=mysql_query("select * from table2 where ID_table1='".$id_table1."'");
$result=mysql_result($select2,0,'result');
```